# Unable to read the data from csv file in aws Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to read the csv file from S3 in Lambda using NodeJS.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const bucket = '';
const objectkey = '';
const params = { Bucket: bucket, Key: objectkey }
const results = [];

exports.handler = async function (event) {
    try {
        const file = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();

        file
            .pipe(csv())
            .on('data', function (data) {
                results.push(data)
            })
            .on('end', () => {
                console.log(results);
            })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

I am getting the result as `null` instead of **csv data**

Answer (score 0):

you did not return the data at any point in your code. you need to call `.succeed()` once done.

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const bucket = '';
const objectkey = '';
const params = { Bucket: bucket, Key: objectkey }
const results = [];

exports.handler = async function (event, ctx, callback) {
    try {
        const file = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();

        file
            .pipe(csv())
            .on('data', function (data) {
                results.push(data)
            })
            .on('end', () => {
                console.log(results);
                callback(null, results);
            })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        callback(Error(err))
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Tuan Anh Tran, am still getting `null`

Comment: My bad, typo, it should be `ctx.succeed(results)` because above i named it `ctx`. also if it doesn't work, can you post the error log?